Is it fine to call a 26 year old character a young adult?
I wa wondering does 26 fall under the category of young adult. I hear its 18-24 or 25 but does 18-26 exist and is that valid?

This is sort of opinion-based, but I would generally say yes. It's not a hard-and-fast rule as to what is or is not a "young adult" - it simply refers to an adult (which is a legally-defined age, usually around 18) who is also young (a subjective adjective).

Your question seems to be about the meaning of English words. I think you will get better answers on English.SE, which is dedicated to questions about the English language.

Are you primarily referring to the chronological age, or the mental/developmental stage of the character?

The Wikipedia article on that age bracket defines "young adult" as

a person in the years following adolescence, sometimes with some overlap. Definitions and opinions on what qualifies as a young adult vary ... ; generally, the term is often used to refer to adults in approximately the age range of 18 to 40 years, with some more inclusive definitions extending the definition into the early to mid 40s. The young adult stage in human development precedes middle adulthood.

The term "middle adulthood" "is commonly used to denote the age range from around 40–45 to around 60–65 years".
So in a work of fiction it is completely appropriate to call someone who is 26 years old a "young adult".

You must not confuse a young adult person, i.e. a person between 18 and 40, with Young Adult fiction (YA), i.e. literature written for teenagers between 12 and 18.

Of course, one must always take Wikipedia with a grain of salt.  The lines are fuzzy, but personally, I would never consider "young adult" an appropriate designation for a 39-year-old, much less a person older than that.

Everything's relative.
If your story is set in the middle ages in a period where children are put to work as early as possible, most people die young because of disease and malnutrition, kings are crowned as early as 9-year-old, and girls are married off as soon as they've had their first period, then no, no one would call a 26-year-old a "young adult".
If your story is set in our time, and a character's parents are paying for all expenses until the character is 25 and finally finished with his studies and finally gets a job, then yes, this 26-year-old is definitely a "young adult".
Perhaps this 26-year-old is already an army lieutenant with lots of responsibilities, but at some point in the story, some mistakes that he makes remind him that he's still only 26 and not that experienced with life. Now he looks in a literal mirror and sees a young adult looking back, when previously in the book he was seeing a successful lieutenant.
You're the author. You get to choose how you paint your characters.

The confusing thing here is that, in literature, "young adult" doesn't actually mean adult at all.
This term denotes books primarily marketed to audiences in the pre-teen to teen age range (though generally also enjoyed by adults of all ages; in this sense the category could be dubbed as "young&adult"), whose heroes also fall in the pre-teen to teen bracket. The story typically includes coming of age and first romance elements (more or less accentuated), and the heroes often tend to be saddled with responsibilities the scope of which would never be expected of their real-life peers. Some examples of what's categorised as young adult protagonists would be Harry Potter (in-story age 11 to 18), Tiffany Aching (age 9 to 17), or Percy Jackson (age 12 to 16).
So your lower margin, 18, is already about the upper margin of what's usually understood as "young adult". 24 is really stretching it; 26 even more. I'd recommend forgoing the term "young adult"; other terms, like "young man" or "young woman", or by profession "young technician", "young detective", "young dragonslayer" or whatever your character is, don't have this meaning-shifting baggage and will probably fit much better.

I agree, in literature "young adult" is 12-18. A better term might be "early adults" for this category of 18-30.

The question is about whether a 26-year-old character in the story should be described as a "young adult", but this answer seems to focus on the age range of the target audience for works in the "young adult" category of literature, and / or on the typical age of the protagonist in such works.  These are different considerations from the descriptions of the characters used within the work itself.
